# Invoking methods for nullable objects in a row with Flow type checking

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I recently applied Flow to my React Native project. So far, most of things are satisfiable.

```
let player ?Object = new Player();
if (this.player) {
    this.player.stop();
    this.player.destroy();
    this.player = null;
}
```

However, Flow wants me to make it like below.

```
let player ?Object = new Player();
if (this.player) {
    this.player.stop();
}
if (this.player) {
    this.player.destroy();
}
this.player = null;
```

Is there any proper way to deal with this kind of situation? I do not want to use suppressing comment for here because it is not an exceptional case.

Comment: https://flowtype.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEAK4E8CmAnA3gXwFCkjAgtGltNAA6KoBcA-NAPIBGAVksAC7QC80AdkgHc4lFAAoAlAG4S0ALYSiM0iCScKYZCm7R2ACwCWEAHTrN00qX0AzaKNOpxiixfsojEdgHsyE88-IiRgAmSB4ongi+Si4i2rwAriAgfqTYqVgYQA

Comment: `let player ?Object = new Player()` should be `let player: ?Object = new Player()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow is pessimistic about type refinements (such as null checks).

In your example, Flow does not know whether the call to `this.player.stop()` sets `this.player` to `null` or `undefined`. Because of that, it has to assume that it might, and invalidates the refinement.

Typically I work around this by pulling properties out into a local variable and operating on that:

```
let player ?Object = new Player();
const constPlayer = this.player;
if (constPlayer) {
    constPlayer.stop();
    constPlayer.destroy();
    this.player = null;
}
```

This is a little more verbose but it's not as bad as doing a separate null check every time.

Check out the [dynamic type tests caveats](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats) section for more info.